# Can't login to joomla administrator page - 404 error

Tags: authentication, joomla

I'm not able to login to the administrator panel at Joomla. It shows me 404 error:

"Not Found
The requested URL /administrator/ was not found on this server.

Apache Server at www.ethic-intelligence.com Port 443"

Please advise.

Comment: No one can confidently answer this question.  You will need to provide more details.   Is this a fresh install?  What version of Joomla are you running?  Did this suddenly happen after you did something? If we cannot reproduce the question, your question is Off-topic/Unclear/Why isn't my code working.  There is also a [joomla.se] Stack Exchange site for Joomla specific support.

Answer (score -2):

The error is most likely caused by a plugin called AdminTools, where you have to add a certain hash to the administrator URL to make it work. If you don't know what that hash is, then you will need to disable the plugin in the `#__extensions` table of the your Joomla database.

Comment: Perhaps it would be best to first ask if the OP _has_ the AdminTools plugin installed under the question, rather than venture a guess.  Please endeavor to clarify questions before answering, not only to make confidently answering easier, but so that the OP learns how to craft a complete question and so that future researchers can better understand the issue/symptoms.